# How to determine the point on the perimeter of a square by adding length?

Tags: swift, math

Given four vectors that represent the corners of a square (v1, v2, v3, and v4), any point along the perimeter of the square (p), and a length (n), how can I determine the point on the perimeter of the square (r) that is the result of adding the length?

For example:

```
let v1 = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
let v2 = CGPoint(x: 10.0, y: 0.0)
let v3 = CGPoint(x: 10.0, y: 10.0)
let v4 = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 10.0)

let corners = [v1, v2, v3, v4]
let p = CGPoint(x: 5.0, y: 0.0)

func add(length n: CGFloat, to p: CGPoint, constrainedTo corners: [CGPoint]) -> CGPoint {
    // …magic!
    return r
}

var n: CGFloat = 17.0
let r = add(length: n, to: p, constrainedTo: corners) // CGPoint(x: 8.0, 10.0)

n: CGFloat = -17.0
let r = add(length: n, to: p, constrainedTo: corners) // CGPoint(x: 2.0, 10.0)

n: CGFloat = -32.8
let r = add(length: n, to: p, constrainedTo: corners) // CGPoint(x: 10.0, y: 2.2)
```

Is the most efficient way to just loop through the “sides”, adding and subtracting as necessary until `n = 0`? Or is there an actual equation for this that I was probably taught in school and forgot?

Comment: Is it always a square?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, it’s always a square.

Comment: Just a nitpick: v1 - v4 are points, not vectors.

Comment: Can the square be rotated at all or will it always be that the sides are parallel with the x/y axes? Are 4 points always specified in clockwise order or can they be counter (anti) clockwise?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a more efficient solution by considering the length of each side and using a mathematical approach to determine the point on the perimeter of the square. In the given scenario, you have a square, so all the sides will have the same length. Here's how you can do it:

1. Calculate the side length of the square using two adjacent vertices.
2. Use that length to calculate which side the resulting point will fall on, and the remaining length within that side.
3. Use linear interpolation to determine the exact point.

Below is a code snippet to accomplish this:

```swift
import CoreGraphics
import Foundation

func add(length n: CGFloat, to p: CGPoint, constrainedTo corners: [CGPoint]) -> CGPoint {
    let sideLength = hypot(corners[0].x - corners[1].x, corners[0].y - corners[1].y)
    let perimeterLength = 4 * sideLength
    
    // Normalize the length to within the range of the perimeter
    var normalizedLength = n.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: perimeterLength)
    if normalizedLength < 0 {
        normalizedLength += perimeterLength
    }
    
    // Determine which side the starting point is on and calculate total distance traveled
    var totalLength: CGFloat = 0
    var sideIndex: Int = 0
    for i in 0..<4 {
        let nextI = (i + 1) % 4
        let sideVector = CGPoint(x: corners[nextI].x - corners[i].x, y: corners[nextI].y - corners[i].y)
        let toPointVector = CGPoint(x: p.x - corners[i].x, y: p.y - corners[i].y)
        
        let dotProduct = sideVector.x * toPointVector.x + sideVector.y * toPointVector.y
        let sideLengthToPoint = dotProduct / sideLength
        
        if sideLengthToPoint >= 0 && sideLengthToPoint <= sideLength {
            totalLength = CGFloat(i) * sideLength + sideLengthToPoint + normalizedLength
            break
        }
    }
    
    // Determine which side the result is on and calculate the final point
    sideIndex = Int(totalLength / sideLength)
    let remainingLength = totalLength.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: sideLength)
    let ratio = remainingLength / sideLength
    
    let startCorner = corners[sideIndex]
    let endCorner = corners[(sideIndex + 1) % 4]
    let r = CGPoint(x: startCorner.x + ratio * (endCorner.x - startCorner.x),
                    y: startCorner.y + ratio * (endCorner.y - startCorner.y))
    
    return r
}

// Usage example:
let v1 = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
let v2 = CGPoint(x: 10.0, y: 0.0)
let v3 = CGPoint(x: 10.0, y: 10.0)
let v4 = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 10.0)
let corners = [v1, v2, v3, v4]
let p = CGPoint(x: 5.0, y: 0.0)
var n: CGFloat = 17.0
let r = add(length: n, to: p, constrainedTo: corners) // CGPoint(x: 8.0, y: 10.0)
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response here. This works for the examples I gave for `p` and `n`, but fails for others.

Comment: If `p = CGPoint(x: 5.0, y: 0.0)` and the value for `n` would produce a result that is less than `p`, there is an array index error. A little print debuging showed this is due to the value for `sideIndex` being set to `4`, which is out of the bounds of the array. Changing `sideIndex = Int(totalLength / sideLength)` to `sideIndex = Int(totalLength / sideLength) % 4` fixes this.

Comment: Even with the above change, it fails to produce the expected result for any point that is not along v1->v2, including v2 itself. For example, if `p = CGPoint(x: 10.0, y: 5.0)` and `n = 1.0`, it produces `r = CGPoint(x: 10.0, y: 1.0)`. It seems that the value for `sideIndex` always ends up being `0` or `4` without the above changes, or `0` with them. I looped through all possible values for `p` and `n`, but the result of `sideLengthToPoint >= 0 && sideLengthToPoint <= sideLength` is always true the first time, which breaks the loop.